# Evaluate Integral using Laplace transform

Tags: integration, laplace-transform

I want to find the integral of the following function using Laplace Transform
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\cos(6t)-\cos(4t)}{t}\,dt
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : write it as $$\int _0^{\infty} \frac {cos 6t- cos 4t}{t} e ^{-st} dt $$

Where s= 0

Now it become Laplace transformation

$$L(\frac {cos 6t- cos 4t}{t}) $$

**We have  property $$L ( \frac{ f(t) }{t}) = \int_s^{\infty}F(s) ds $$
Here $F(s) = L(f(t)) $**

Using above property

$L(\frac {cos 6t- cos 4t}{t}) = \int_s^{\infty} \left(\frac{s}{s^2+6^2}-\frac{s}{s^2+4^2} \right) ds$

Integrate you will get
$$=\frac{1}{2}\ln(\frac{s^2+4^2}{s^2+6^2}) $$

Now put s=0

= $$=\frac{1}{2}\ln(\frac{4^2}{6^2}) $$

$$= \ln ( 2/3) $$

Comment: $s=0$ must be replaced by $\underset{s\to 0}{\mathop{\lim }}\,$